# Sharepoint 2010 - Exporting config settings for all lists, workflows, and libraries

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, reporting-services

Is there a way to export the design/setup of all my lists, libraries and workflows?  I'm looking for something kind of like this:

List 1:

```
Permissions:  
Columns:
Associated Workflows:
```

Workflow 1:

```
Starts when item is edited
Associated List
```

Anything remotely like this?

Thanks

Comment: It can be done with really complex powershell script and i dont think that here is anybody who will spend lots of time with this... Maybe when i have some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write powershell script to make this kind of documentation. Alternatively there is some 3rd party software that could do it for you like you SPDocKit (I recommend this one as I use myself) or docusnap.